# Which Language has better Threading functionality? PHP or Ruby

Tags: php, ruby

I am creating a web application which requires threading and I am trying to figure out which langauge between PHP and Ruby has better threading functionality and better performance.

Even if not in built, some easy work arounds or add-ons.

Comment: Why do you need threading for a web app?  Are you really doing so much processing for a single request that it requires multiple threads?  If so, won't your server be overwhelmed easily?

Comment: @tloach Threading doesn't necessarily mean overwhelming processing. It simply reduces the processing time. Time to process in serial could be 10s or 1s, it doesn't matter. The point is reducing whatever that time is. You can always just throw more hardware at it, anyway.

Comment: @Lucas: Except web apps are multithreaded by virtue of being web, each request is dealt with in a different process.  Multithreading is unlikely to give performance gains on a system where all cores are already busy, in fact it can reduce performance since it introduces overhead.

Comment: @tloach Yes, you're right. Sorry for the confusion. When I used the term "threading", I was using a more liberal definition; c.f. my answer below (specifically: web services).

Comment: So basically, my web app needs to run a few thousand queries in 5 mins in the background. I cannot run this from one thread because one thread will only run about a fourth of the queries that I need and the time period cannot be more than 5 mins hence need threading. What do you think?

Answer (score 9):

I would have to say Ruby, since Ruby actually supports it. PHP does not.

With PHP, you can create new processes (which is a bad idea) or write multiple web services and use curl_multi_* functions to accomplish some things, but threading is not a feature of PHP.

Comment: So basically, my web app needs to run a few thousand queries in 5 mins in the background. I cannot run this from one thread because one thread will only run about a fourth of the queries that I need and the time period cannot be more than 5 mins hence need threading. What do you think?

Comment: Why do web apps run background processing?

Comment: Apologies about my terminology but basically my application consists of the front-end and this background processing module.

Answer (score 5):

These are probably the two worst languages to choose if you want threading, but if you really want one of these two, I guess Ruby can do it. Better go with JRuby, though. The JVM does very excellent threading.

(Or go with Groovy, which is basically Java with lots of Rubyisms.)

Answer (score 2):

PHP does not normally do threading.

Answer (score 2):

PHP does not have threading (good thing IMO).

Ruby has, but in 1.8 it has green threads, where in 1.9 it has a GIL. What this means (in the case of MRI and YARV - the 1.8 and 1.9 main Ruby implementations) is that 2 threads cannot run at the same time (in both cases) and you can't take advantage of multi-core processors.

You can use processes in both languages to overcome those limitations.

Comment: It is not true that green threads can't take advantage of multi-core processors. Counterexamples are Erlang and MzScheme, among many others. It is also not true that Ruby 1.8 has green threads. There is nothing in the Ruby Specification that forces a Ruby Implementation to use green threads, and indeed, all Ruby 1.8 implementations except one use native threads. And it is not true that Ruby 1.9 has a GIL. Again, there is nothing in the Ruby Spec that forces implementations to have a GIL and most of them don't.

Comment: Jörg - correct! When I was talking about Ruby I generally meant MRI (JRuby has proper threading support).

Answer (score 2):

PHP currently has no support for the explicit use of threads; your PHP server may or may not use threads to serve different HTTP request ( the Zend engine does, I believe), but there are no facilities to create or coordinate threads via PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

Neither may be good way to achieve what you are trying.

Consider looking at [Gearman](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gearman.php) for asynchronous processing of "jobs". If your are looking to loosely couple your service with other services then you need a messaging service such as [RabbitMQ](http://www.slideshare.net/old_sound/integrating-rabbitmq-with-php).

It seems like [Gearman](http://gearman.org/index.php) will fit your needs.